# java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseImage to field

Tags: java, jasper-reports, classcastexception

I am working on JasperReports Library in my jsf project. First of all I am just developing a simple project by this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D2IsIzcuyBo)

But in this tutorial there is no guide to how to install complete libraries of JasperReports.

I try it to my self but getting exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseImage to field net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBasePen.penContainer of type net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRPenContainer in instance of net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBasePen

and

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseImage to field net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBasePen.penContainer of type net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRPenContainer in instance of net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBasePen
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2133)
```

Here is my method where I am trying to generate report:

```
JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanCollectionDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(listOfStudent);
String reportPath = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/reports/ChartReport.jasper");
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportPath, new HashMap(), beanCollectionDataSource);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, outputStream);
```

and my libraries those I am using without any guide:

[image]

Can anyone tell me where I am doing mistake, I hope its due to missing some important library but I cannot fine any appropriate link for downloading libraries.

Comment: Are you sure that it is necessary to use so old version (1.2.0)?

Comment: it is not necessary.

Comment: In this case it is better to use 6.2.2 version (last version). You can try to use maven dependencies

Comment: Any suitable link?

Answer (score 0):

You have both jasperreports-1.2.0.jar (which is very old as Alex K observed) and jasperreports-javaflow.jar (unspecified version) on your project's classpath.

jasperreports-javaflow jars are variants of the jasperreports jars with classes instrumented for the Javaflow based subreport runner.  You should not have both jasperreports.jar and jasperreports-javaflow.jar on the classpath; keep the vanilla jasperreports.jar unless you specifically need the Javaflow subreport runner.